# JS Error causing slider not to work

Tags: javascript, magento, slider

I'm setting up a Magento Store and I'm using the HelloWired theme.

There's a slider included with the theme called HelloSlide, which basically crossfades between two images.

For some reason, it seems like both images are transitioning to eachother at the same time. This causes no image to show.

Here's what the markup, which was included in the template looks like:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="panel"><img src="http://50.63.156.40/media/helloslide/01.jpg" alt="Flowing Rock" />
  <div class="panel"><img src="http://50.63.156.40/media/helloslide/02.jpg" alt="Other" /> 
  <div id="controls"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say its because the panel divs is not closed after the images:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="panel"><img src="http://50.63.156.40/media/helloslide/01.jpg" alt="Flowing Rock" />
  <div class="panel"><img src="http://50.63.156.40/media/helloslide/02.jpg" alt="Other" /> 
  <div id="controls"> </div>
</div>
```

should be changed to:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="panel"><img src="http://50.63.156.40/media/helloslide/01.jpg" alt="Flowing Rock" /></div>
  <div class="panel"><img src="http://50.63.156.40/media/helloslide/02.jpg" alt="Other" /> </div>
  <div id="controls"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the code that I copied directly from their documentation. Pretty much every piece of code in their docs had problems with Div opens and closes. Thank you so much.